# Best Way To Farm Shotgun Kills For New Light Players?

Tags: destiny-2

I am a new light player and I am looking to complete the Felwinter’s Lie quest. One of the quest steps is to get 1000 shotgun kills. Can anyone tell me the best place to get these kills? All other guides I have seen on the internet tell that the best places to go are the shattered throne or the last wish raid, neither of which I have access to since I don’t own any dlc. Help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can no longer get the Felwinter's Lie shotgun, but for anyone looking to farm kills, you can either do the Escalation Protocol on Mars, or enter the Whisper mission and go to the thrall room under the big open green area with the parkour. The latter has infinitely-spawning thrall and the only downside is the 20 minute timer.